# Table/List Layout in Android

Tags: android

I'm currently developing an Android application, and I need to do sth. like this: [image]

(I know It's in german, but you get the idea)

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Well this is kind of broad as it could be done a lot of different ways. You could use a RelativeLayout, or nested LinearLayouts. Have you tried something yet and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would do this using two nested LinearLayouts. One vertical LL for each row, and in each a horizontal LL for individual rows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Speicherort"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Meine Dateien"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ordnerpfad"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/storage/emulated/0"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

By setting the width of the TVs to 0dp and both layout weights to 1 this means they will each take up 50% of the width, so the right and left sides will be divided evenly.

If you need to change the text programatically, just search for the id and use `setText()`:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_one);
textView.setText("Speicherort");
```

Comment: Perfect, but there's a typo: "andorid" instead of "android".

Comment: Nevertheless, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

So what you want is a row that is divided equally right?

You can do this by wrapping the row in a `LinearLayout` and setting `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` to each of the `TextView`'s.

Or you could use a [`PercentRelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html).